# sub or function not defined

Tags: vba

My code is written below. When I run it, I get a

> 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

in this line:

```
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j).Value, Cells(1063, j + 4).Value)
```

I am new to VBA and I don't understand what's going wrong.

```
Sub MLNRealworldtransfer()
Dim MLNRange As Range
Dim MLNDensity As Double
For i = 10 To 23
For j = 1 To 116
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j).Value, Cells(1063, j + 4).Value)
MLNDensity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 122).Value, MLNRange, 5, "True")
MLNDensity = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 125)
i = i + 1
Next
j = j + 9
Next
```

**Edit 1:**

I made changes and  I take compile error  sub or function not defined in the following code

```
Sub MLNRealworldtran()
Dim MLNRange As Range
Dim MLNDensity As Double
For i = 10 To 23 Step 2
For j = 1 To 116 Step 10
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(1063, j + 4))
MLNDensity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("GJR     GARCH").Cells(i, 122).Value, MLNRange, 5, "True")
MLNDensity = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 131)
Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:** you had "nexti" and "nextj" which is what was throwing the error. Should be "Next i" and "Next j"

Comment: get rid of the .value on all cells on that line.  they are not needed

Comment: Okay, where is it causing a problem? Whenever vba has an error, it highlights the offending piece of code.

Comment: Next i gets blue I take compile error sub or function not defined and if I press ok  Sub MLNRealworldtran() gets yellow

Comment: You were using "nexti" instead of "next I"

Comment: In future. Put "option explicit" at the top of every module. It means you have to explicitly create every variable and any new ones (e.g. a mis-spelling) will be flagged for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems. First,

```
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j).Value, Cells(1063, j + 4).Value)
```

.value isn't a range, it's a property. Just use the cell references

```
    Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(1063, j + 4))
```

Second, your increment variables aren't nested correctly

```
For i = 1 to 10
for j = 1 to 10
next i
next j

'/ should be

for i
for j

next j
next i
```

You can define steps in the for statement. E.g.

```
For i = 10 to 23 step 2
for j = 1 to 116 step 10
'/ Code
next j
next i

i will then go 10, 12, 14, 16 etc. and j will go 1, 11, 21, 31 etc.
```

Rather than referencing `Sheets("GJR GARCH")` everywhere (which is messy and a pain to change). Define your worksheet as  variable then reference that.

```
Dim wsData as Worksheet
    wsData = Sheets("GJR GARCH")

    MLNDensity = wsData.Cells(i, 125)
```

Comment: now ther seems to be a problem with next i              Sub MLNRealworldtran()
Dim MLNRange As Range
Dim MLNDensity As Double
For i = 10 To 23 Step 2
For j = 1 To 116 Step 10
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(1063, j + 4))
MLNDensity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 122).Value, MLNRange, 5, "True")
MLNDensity = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 131)
Nexti
Nextj
End Sub

Comment: If you've changed your code and the new code isn't working. Please add the new code as an edit to the bottom of the question. I'm not about to try and read code in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

.Value don't belong in there:

```
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(1063, j + 4))
```

Also your incrementing of loop variables i and j inside the loops seems odd. You can write e.g.

```
For i = 10 To 23 Step 2
```

Comment: good catch on the increment.  The for j = 1 to 116 should step 10

Comment: I wanted to leave j as generalization task for the OP. :) @ScottCraner

Comment: hmm why add step 2? now I get run time error 1004 unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Comment: you need to remove the i=i+1 and j=j+9 when using the steps.

Comment: Sub MLNRealworldtran()
Dim MLNRange As Range
Dim MLNDensity As Double
For i = 10 To 23 Step 2
For j = 1 To 116 Step 10
Set MLNRange = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(1063, j + 4))
MLNDensity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 122).Value, MLNRange, 5, "True")
MLNDensity = Sheets("GJR GARCH").Cells(i, 131)
Nexti
Nextj
End Sub                     now I take Sub or function not defined